# tkinter notebook.tab: text (title) displayed incorrectly

Tags: python, tabs, tkinter, widget, ttk

I am trying to create a own Framework and for this I want to make a GUI using `tkinter` on an Apple computer.

It seems that the `text` (the title) of `notebook.tabs` is not displayed properly on Mac OS X as shown below:

[image]

As you can see the `text` is not centered horizontally and is slightly displaced to the top.

My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class SpiderGUI():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding=(10, 10, 10, 10))
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

        self.paned_window = ttk.Panedwindow(self.frame, orient="horizontal")
        self.paned_window.pack(fill="both", expand="True")

        self.frame_settings = ttk.Frame(self.paned_window, width=75, height=300, relief="sunken")
        self.paned_window.add(self.frame_settings)
        self.frame_output   = ttk.Frame(self.paned_window, width=950, height=300, relief="sunken")
        self.paned_window.add(self.frame_output, weight="4")
        self.frame_logging  = ttk.Frame(self.paned_window, width=175, height=500, relief="sunken")
        self.paned_window.add(self.frame_logging)


        self.console_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.frame_output)
        self.console_notebook.pack()

        self.frame_tab_console = ttk.Frame(self.console_notebook)
        self.console_notebook.add(self.frame_tab_console, text="Console", padding=(10))

        self.frame_tab_database = ttk.Frame(self.console_notebook)
        self.console_notebook.add(self.frame_tab_database, text="MongoDB")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = SpiderGUI(root)
    # root.geometry(newGeometry="1200x800+100+100")
    root.title('name')
    root.resizable(width=True, height=False)
    # root.maxsize(width=1280, height=1024)
    # root.minsize(width=640, height=480)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a proper sketch illustrating what you want to get as a result. Do you want to have those notebook tabs in the middle of your three-column design?

Comment: The TEXT within the Tabs are not centered. The TABS itself are alright. I have them at this moment with style.configure('TNotebook', tabposition='nw'). But the TEXT: Console and MongoDB are not in the middle of the tab.

Comment: All right. I didn't see that at the first time. However, this seems to be a bug in tkinter (Pyhon 3.4.3, Mac OS 10.10.5) since the same appears on older project I have been working on. There could be some bugfixes in the meantime in new tkinter releases provided by [ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads) as recommended by [Python.org](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/). However, to be honest, I do not have any idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

If someone else still needs a solution to this. This is hacky but works:

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TNotebook.Tab', padding=(20, 8, 20, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be nicer to apply the fixing answered by mrushabh only for OSX, like this:

```
root = tk.Tk()

# a fix for running on OSX - to center the title text vertically
if root.tk.call('tk', 'windowingsystem') == 'aqua':  # only for OSX
    s = ttk.Style()
    # Note: the name is specially for the text in the widgets
    s.configure('TNotebook.Tab', padding=(12, 8, 12, 0))
```